# Compiling C++ with VSCode on the Mac

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code

Total novice C++ user going thru tutorials using Visual Studio Code on OSX. Barest bones Hello World program

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello, World!";
    return 0;
}
```

Then I run-compile in VSCodes terminal using

```
$ g++ Foo.cpp -o foo
```

My question is, shouldn't I be seeing the Hello, World! out put in the terminal? Or will this only be visible if I compile and run in Windows?
I do see an executable after compiling but nothing in the VS Terminal window.

Comment: Compiling the program does not *run* the program, it just creates the executable file. You need to first compile it, then *run* it.

Comment: use ./foo to run it after you compile it.

Comment: You have to execute the program to see "Hello, World! ". The program being the executable file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually have to run the file. So, in this case, since you named your file "foo" with the -o command, you have to run ./foo from the terminal.